# Are there various formulas generating generalized linear mixed-effects models(GLMM)in lme4 package?

Tags: effect, glmm

I am reproducing a GLMM with the data given in a published paper. The author mentioned that lme4 package was used in the analysis. I am using glmer() and in summary(),I am able to get the correct AIC. However, the fixed effects(e.g. estimate, std. error, z value, and Pr) do not match with the statistics in the paper.

Is there any formula, other than glmer(), that can generate GLMM with different effect size?